# Apple maps route request URL from current location

Tags: ios, google-maps, maps

I'm now thinking about an app for iOS, which could send an SMS to other people (without Internet connection) with a URL link to give them offline direction to my location in native maps app when they tap the link.
 I know it can be done with this kind of URL:

```
http://maps.apple.com/maps?saddr=<their location>&daddr=<my location, filled by my app>
```

Of course I could leave `saddr` blank and let them pick their current location from the autocomplete list for start point, but it's gonna take them 1 more step to get the direction. I just want to make sure to give them the most convenient way.

How to guide the native maps app to automatically get SMS receiver user's current location by this URL? I need some thing like this:

```
http://maps.apple.com/maps?saddr=current_location&daddr=<my location, filled by my app>
```

I also want to send this link to other platform user, like with Android user I could use:

```
http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=current_location&daddr=<my location, filled by my app>
```

Windows Phone (I haven't known yet):

```
http://maps.???.com/maps?saddr=current_location&daddr=<my location, filled by my app>
```

Any keyword or answer will be very appreciated!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You were pretty close!

Apple Maps:

```
http://maps.apple.com/maps?saddr=Current%20Location&daddr=<Your Location>
```

Google Maps:

```
comgooglemaps-x-callback://?saddr=&daddr=<Your Location>
```

Comment: This works.  For google maps, you can not add the saddr parameter and will work, the apple way is kinda dumb, current location should be the default but you need to writhe current%20location.  Thanks.

Comment: I agree. Apple is a bit behind the times there. No problem - glad to be of help.

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer. I was unaware of the "Current%20Location" parameter value. I was attempting to get the location first from a Cordova/Ionic app with the geolocation plugin before calling maps for navigation directions. This is MUCH nicer. Thanks!

Comment: Google: [Documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/urlscheme) Apple: Tested it.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using objective-c:

```
    NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"maps.apple.com/maps?saddr=&daddr=%@,%@",destinationLatitude,destinationLongitude];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
```

If you are using swift 2.2:

```
    var string = "http://maps.apple.com/?saddr=&daddr=\(destinationLatitude),\(destinationLongitude)"
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string: string)!)
```

If you are using swift 3.0:

```
    var string = "http://maps.apple.com/?saddr=&daddr=\(destinationLatitude),\(destinationLongitude)"
    UIApplication.shared.openURL(URL(string: string)!)
```

Answer (score 0):

in My Case Best Way To Connect inside Chat :

```
let OptionMenu = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: nil, preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
let GoogleMap = UIAlertAction(title: "Open Google Map".localized, style: .default) { (alert) in
    if let url = URL(string: "comgooglemaps://?saddr=&daddr=\(Lat),\(Lng)&directionsmode=driving"),
       UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url) {
        print("comgoogle maps worked")
        if #available(iOS 10, *) {
            UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler:nil)
        } else {
            UIApplication.shared.openURL(url)
        }
    }

}
let OpenMaps = UIAlertAction(title: "Open Maps".localized, style: .default) { (alert) in
    if let url = URL(string: "http://maps.apple.com/?saddr=&daddr=\(Lat),\(Lng)"),
       UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url) {
        print("Maps maps worked")
        if #available(iOS 10, *) {
            UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler:nil)
        } else {
            UIApplication.shared.openURL(url)
        }
    }
}
OptionMenu.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel".localized, style: .cancel, handler: nil))

OptionMenu.addAction(GoogleMap)
OptionMenu.addAction(OpenMaps)
self.present(OptionMenu, animated: true, completion: nil)
```